# select2 removes default options when using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am trying to setup my pre defined select options in [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax) 
with ajax
but when I am using the ajax and clicking on the select2 it removes the html options I had there before, any idea how can I make it to leave the options as they are and not remove them until I am typing some unrelevant char?

I believe it is not clear so I made fiddle with both cases so you will get better understanding

**the HTML**

```
<select id="e1" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>


<select id="e2" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
```

**the js**

```
$("#e1").select2({ajax: {
    url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, page) {
      // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
      // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
      // alter the remote JSON data
      return {
        results: data.items
      };
    },
    cache: true
  }});

$("#e2").select2();
```

**[fiddle example of select2 ajax and none ajax](http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/1761/)**

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080739/select2-default-options-with-ajax

Answer (score -2):

In your server side script, where you are processing the search query the user sent, return the first 5 elements which should appear as default, even if the query is empty.

```
 $query=$_REQUEST['q'];
 if (!empty($query)) {
     //populate the results if the user is typed something in
 } else {
   $results=array();
   $results[0]['text']=Alabama;
   $results[0]['id']="idofalabama";
   // and so on, for the number of results you want to display when the user didn't input anything in the search box
 }
 return json_encode($results);
```